# How to manage type definition files that aren't downloaded via typings?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an `Angular` app where I'm using `npm` and `typings` to manage pulling down my type definition files `.d.ts` for `TypeScript`. However I have a few `.d.ts` files that don't exist in `typings` and are either hand rolled or downloaded from an alternate source manually.

From a project structure perspective, how should I manage these *outsider* type definition files in the project? Is it correct to just add them manually to the `typings/global` folder, and then add a reference to `index.d.ts`, or is this problematic and these should be placed separately in a segregated spot away from the files managed by `typings`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the options would be pointing *typings.json* to your custom definitions file. For example having the following folder structure:

```
/typings
    /custom
        hand-rolled.d.ts
    /global
        ...
```

*typings.json* will have reference pointing to file system:

```
"globalDependencies": {
    "hand-rolled": "file:typings/custom/hand-rolled.d.ts"
}
```

You'll not need manually add a reference to index.d.ts. And you can check in `typings/custom` into source control.

Comment: The only caveat to this suggestion is normally I completely exclude the `/typings` folder from source control. In this case I'd have to whitelist just the `/custom` directory.

Comment: @atconway it is just example, you can put this file in any other directory. Personally I do it exactly as you said - exclude `/typings` and whitelist `/custom`

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you shouldn't be adding your own type declarations to the `typings` folder, because unless I am mistaken you are not meant to check the `typings` folder into source control - the same way you don't check-in your `node_modules`.

It's up to you how you want to structure your typings, but it would make sense to physically separate ambient/global and external modules.

Also - why not contribute your type declarations to the project you have created them for or the [`typings` registry](https://github.com/typings/registry)?

Comment: The hand rolled type definition files I'm speaking about reflect my `C#` types returned as `json` via RESTful calls on the server, and are custom so they wouldn't be a good fit (from my understand) to have them in the `typings registry` as no one else would use them.