# How to add typings of the library manually

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to use Typescript, and I am stuck with external library which doesn't have typings.
I use typings, so all references are resolved through typings folder.

The question is, what is the best way to declare such typings? To create folder `myTypings` and then reference these files directly?

**UPD**
My typings.json file is:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "react": "registry:dt/react#0.14.0+20160630100702",
    "react-dom": "registry:dt/react-dom#0.14.0+20160412154040",
    "react-redux": "registry:dt/react-redux#4.4.0+20160703120921",
    "redux": "registry:dt/redux#3.5.2+20160703092728",
    "redux-logger": "registry:dt/redux-logger#2.6.0+20160619033847"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "redux-thunk": "registry:npm/redux-thunk#2.0.0+20160525185520"
  }
}
```

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082431/how-to-manage-type-definition-files-that-arent-downloaded-via-typings/38091045#38091045) question.

Comment: What is the content of your file `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Paleo I've added it.